# Reload file.js every minute

Tags: javascript

I read (somewhere else on this site) you can't reload (or inject javascript) onto a page that is already rendered.
Is there any other way of doing this. For instance an iFrame?

I have a recent comment widget.js and I need to constantly get it to reload without reloading the whole page.

Any ideas?

edit: The site has recent comments on it and they are displayed via a recentcomment.js
Once the page is loaded it doesn't update itself unless you reload the page. I want it to update itself, a way to do this is to just reload the js file on the page, correct?

Comment: If you need to reload the js file every minute, then there's something really seriously wrong with your architecture. Please describe the problem you're trying to solve, and hopefully someone can suggest a better solution.

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the whole thing in a function and call that every minute?

Comment: Or make an periodic AJAX call to some data source containing the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to do this? It seems to me that there's probably a more appropriate solution to your problem.

But to answer it:

```
var elm = document.createElement("script");
elm.src = "Widget.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(elm);
```

Hope I didn't write any mistakes...

Comment: If the page is done rendering, would it still load the contents of the js file?

Comment: You might need to add a random parameter to the end, eg. `Widget.js?1234` to prevent caching.

Comment: If you wrap that code in a function and repetitively call it every x seconds, it keeps reloading the js file

Comment: -1: see http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx . You might be able to come up with correct answer that solves the problem the way the OP wanted to, but I'm going to be very frank: the strategy the OP is simply a bad way to solve his particular problem. It might seem like a fun challenge to solve, but in all seriousness, please don't encourage the OP to write code like this. Try to encourage solving problems using the right tools and techniques, and don't be afraid to tell the OP there are better ways than hack he's trying to use.

Comment: @Juliet who is the OP? what does that stand for? any other acronyms I need to know here?

Comment: OP == original post or original poster.

Comment: @Juliet it's not a hack. I have to get the recent comments to update and they only come in a js file from another server. I didn't write the code. I'm trying to solve a problem. A hack that works would actually be great. NNTGYPIAB

Comment: @Bart that is actually the same idea the professional coders use to initially display the script. I just can't get it to reload. I tried the function thing to no avail. good thinking anyway!

Comment: @Juliet I'm not encouraging him... At the time I posted this reply, the problem wasn't as clear as it is now. So I explicitly said there's probably a better solution, but if he still wants to know how to load scripts on-the-fly, I give him his answer. In what way am I encouraging him or am I afraid to say it's not a good practice?

Comment: @gravityboy: You think reloading widget.js is going to solve your problem. However, I'm sure widget.js only contains the code for displaying the comments, not the actual comments themselves. What you need to do is reload the comments, not the widget.js script. What's the site you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reloading the file, you can have all the implementation of the file contained in a function and then call the function every minute using the `setTimeout()` function.

Alternatively, if you want to reload it because the content of the file might have changed, it would probably be better to move that part of the code out to some external file and then use a function (running every minute with `setTimeout()`) to load the new content you need.

Comment: the recent comments.js are coming from another sever.

Answer (score 0):

You can make cross-domain AJAX requests using certain methods, so you could make an AJAX request for the script file and parse it yourself. Parsing it yourself probably isn't an optimal solution, but it looks like you're dealing with a brain-dead service provider anyways.

Look at this guy's jQuery mod for an example:
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Once you get the data from the 3rd party, you could probably use some combination of regex and JSON parser to extract the comments.